# Unable to install Canon printer drivers for a network connection while using an account with administrative privileges

Tags: windows, networking, drivers, printer, administrator

I have a Canon MF644CDW all-in-one laser printer. I was able to install the [drivers](https://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/6/0100010286/02/MF642CMFDriverV6403W64.exe) for a network connection without any problems on my personal laptop running Windows 10.

However, when I try to install the drivers on my work laptop running Windows 10, I try to do the same thing and select "Network Connection":

[image]

Then when I click Next, I get this error:

> You do not have sufficient privileges to install the program. Log on again with administrator privileges.

But I am using the local Windows account with administrator privileges that our IT department created for me to install programs. I have used this local admin account tons of times to install programs, and never had a problem with it.

I did try to see if the local admin account could install the drivers with the "USB Connection" option selected, and that worked fine. The driver installation only shows the error message when "Network Connection" is selected. But the USB connection option does not work for me, since I need to use a wireless network connection.

I tried running the `MF642CMFDriverV6403W64.exe` installation program by right-clicking on it and selecting "Run as administrator", and got the error message. I also tried opening a command line using the local admin account and running `MF642CMFDriverV6403W64.exe` from there, and also got the error message.

I noticed that the `MF642CMFDriverV6403W64.exe` installation program extracts a bunch of files and then runs a `Setup.exe` file before prompting for the "Type of Connection". So I tried to run the `Setup.exe` file directly (by right-clicking "Run as administrator" and also from an admin command line) and still got the error message.

I looked around on the internet and other people also get this same error message with Canon printer drivers (different models too) when selecting the "Network Connection" option. I have not seen any solution though.

Comment: Connect the printer to your local network with Ethernet cable (much preferred) and give it a static IP address on the network. Use the Printer Control Panel to do this. Then install again and connect it to the IP address either with TCP/IP or with a WSD port. See if that works.

Comment: The printer and router are on different floors. Also, I'd still have to select "Network Connection" in the installer, so I don't see why it wouldn't fail with the same error message again.

Comment: You need to talk to your IT. Administrator rights means, more than anything, you have permission to change the rights of other things. There are ways to block an admin from installing things, but not to prevent them from changing those permissions back. And so you need to speak with your IT staff about what needs to be changed to adjust the system permissions so that you can then run the installer.

Comment: Because this question is about a work computer, it is off-topic for SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is not a permission issue with the local admin account. One of our IT guys tried using his own admin account to run the installer and got the same error I got.

I had been logged into my normal user account and used "Run as administrator" with the local admin account credentials to run the installer. The IT guy said he's seen some installers that don't work if you try to run them by doing a "Run as administrator" while logged in as a non-admin user, and that you have to actually login to an administrator account to get them to work.

So I logged in as the local admin account, ran the installer, and got the drivers successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

Installed as a USB printer and then changed the port in Printer Preferences to the proper network port.  That worked but it shouldn't be this hard to install a printer.

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple accounts that were in the Administrator group (this is a corporate device), the local Administrator account was used.  Once the local Administrator account was logged in, the software successfully installed with the Network option.

There is no reason why the driver should not have respected the Administrator privileges of the domain accounts.  This needs to be reviewed by Canon and fixed in future versions.